# gradle, composite builds, jacoco and sonarqube

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, jacoco, sonarcloud

So my team has a monorepo.
it has multiple included builds, either applications or libraries.

We are aiming to start using sonarqube/jacoco for test coverage, yet... well, there's no documentation anywhere regarding how to achieve it.

Only limitation is that I need a merged report.

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_report_aggregation_plugin.html “_The JaCoCo Report Aggregation plugin (plugin id: jacoco-report-aggregation) provides the ability to aggregate the results of multiple JaCoCo code coverage reports (potentially spanning multiple Gradle projects) into a single HTML report._” Is this what you’re looking for?

Comment: Ohh I did it, I'll post the answer later on. It's pretty ugly, but it can be done